# Swift 3 TapGestureRecognizer selector throwing error

Tags: swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've looked at a couple of other post with issues of adding a target to not just tap gestures and buttons and I think I am following the formatting correctly but am still getting the 'has no member' error, here's my pseudo code:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlTap(_:)))

func handleTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the gesture to your view:

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(yourGesture)
```

Answer (score 1):

To access any object with UITapGestureRecognizer

```
  let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.expand))
  view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
  func expand(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
   if let myImg = sender.view as? UIImageView //or AnyObject you want {

}
  }
```